# MySQL: does GROUP BY works while either after searching rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

"The GROUP BY clause groups a set of rows into a set of summary rows by values of columns or expressions. The `GROUP BY` clause returns one row for each group. In other words, it reduces the number of rows in the result set." - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

But when actually `GROUP BY` works? When rows are searched, either after they all are found (filters the result of the query)?

Comment: You might want to google mysql order of operations - here's one https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. If you're thinking of the database in terms of loops over data evaluating truths for the WHERE part, then you could probably envisage the group by as being a dictionary/hashtable. It makes sense for performance reasons to do the hashing at the same time that you loop the data, but you could loop twice; once to filter, once to group. The looping part is cheap

How you write your query can have a bearing on things too. All in there's a lack of specifics on your question that prohibits a direct and targeted answer.

For your particular query you might get the info you need from the Display Execution Plan facility; filtering and grouping may show up separately there and you'll then be able to infer when they're done